# Why a child div is not being removed when the height of parent div is decreased to 0?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm very new to HTML and CSS. So please bear with me.

I've a `header` div, which contains a `nav` div, which contains a `li` div. I was trying to implement a button which would hide the `header`. I'm able to hide the `header`, but I can still see the `nav` and `li` div.

The following are the css properties:

```css
#header {
  z-index: 100;
  left:0;
  top: 0px;
  height: 60px;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
    nav {
       max-width: 650px;
       margin: 0 auto;
       padding: 0 10px;
       li {
          font-family: 'OpenSansLight', "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
          font-weight: normal;
          list-style: none;
          display: inline;
          color: white;
          line-height: 50px;
       }
    }
}
```

The above is a Jekyll `scss` file, which generates a corresponding `css`. The JavaScript function is as follows:

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    console.log(content.innerHTML);
    if (content.style.height){
      content.style.height = null;
    } else {
      content.style.height = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Use `display: none;` for hiding elements.

Comment: I actually want to create a transition from max-height to zero, so I did not use `display: None`. However, that works fine. The child divs are hidden as well.

Comment: Check out this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow

Comment: Thanks @Paul. The default value of `overflow` is `visible`, so this wasn't working.

Comment: So now it works, correct? To be sure: The `overflow: visible` caused the child elements to be visible, even though the parent had a height of 0.

Comment: Yes @Paul, it works now. Yes, `overflow:visible` caused the child to be visible.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please use the display property as none. It will hide children divs also.
Use like this : `display: 'none';`

Comment: I actually want to create a transition from max-height to zero, so I did not use display: None. However, that works fine. The child divs are hidden as well.